# Python- Implement database table where each row has different column names

Tags: python, database

I have to implement a database table in Python where each row can have different column names. Something like: [this image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vf4tk.jpg).. I have no knowledge of DBMS or MySQL. please guide me if they have anything in common.

Comment: I  wouldn't call that a database table, since this usually refers to relational databases. You could serialize an array of dictionaries using the pickle module.

Comment: Both *implement a database table* and *I have no knowledge of DBMS* sounds unclear. It looks like you are asking a question without knowing the words it it...

Answer (score 0):

You will need a non-relational database if your "schema" (column names) is different for every row. [TinyDB package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tinydb) seems suitable for your use case and a good start if you don't have much experience with databases. If you need more performance, I would suggest look elsewhere, for instance [MongoDB](https://www.mongodb.com/).